# Где лучше хранить номер банковской карты пользователя?

Tags: безопасность, банковские-карты

Нужно хранить номер банковской карты, чтобы не утруждать пользователя заполнять его каждый раз.
Есть два места, где можно хранить номер карты - в базе данных сервиса, на телефоне пользователя.
Но какой из вариантов безопаснее. 
Для работы системы хранить карты необязательно, достаточно для операции вывода передать эти самые реквизиты. Поэтому напрашивается вывод, что лучше чтобы номер карты хранился у пользователя.
Но не создаст ли это уязвимость для пользователя?

Comment: Насколько я помню, правила всяких виз и мастеркардов категорически запрещают хранить номера карт и за это может прилететь большой штраф

Comment: @andreymal номера-то хранить можно, каждый второй сервис (а среди подписочных сервисов - каждый первый) предлагает сохранить данные карты. Хотя, подозреваю, есть требования к шифрованию и надежности хранения вообще. Вот CVV/CVC2 хранить действительно запрещено.

Comment: @Yaant все эти сервисы имеют сертификат PCI DSS и проходят регулярные проверки безопасности. И я сильно сомневаюсь, что автор вопроса имеет такой сертификат, иначе вопроса и не возникло бы ;)

Comment: получается вообще ни в каком виде не хранить? пускай пользователи вручную по 2 раза на дню вводят?

Comment: @ИванАнтонов пускай пользователи пользуются платёжной системой, имеющей сертификат PCI DSS, и вводят все свои данные туда. Вам знать номера карт вообще незачем, пусть за это отвечает платёжная система

Comment: @andreymal Судя по [этому](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/why-doesnt-the-clients-web-browser-need-to-be-pci-compliant), браузер может хранить, не обладая сертификатом. Но если автору вопроса кроме хранения понадобится еще и как-то использовать эти данные, то тут без сертификата не обойтись. :)